# REST api Get request in MVC when using a model as parameter

Tags: asp.net-core

If i have a rest api with a GET endpoint such as

\users

i also have a UserSearchModel class for example

```
public class UserSearchModel
{
  public string firstName {get;set;}
  public string lastName {get;set;}
  public string userCode {get;set;}
}
```

is it possible to have a controller action such as

```
public async... GetUsers(UserSearchModel searchParams)
```

without sending the data in request body, if i send in query string instead will the model binding still work?

Comment: Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send each properties as a query string yes

```
http://example.com/url?firstName=madu&lastName=Alikor&usercode=123
```